# Merge series in sql removing dupes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple audit log tables, and I'm trying to figure out a way to join these in SQL to produce an overall audit log.

```sql
create table firstname_history(userid int, name string, timestamp date);
insert into firstname_history values 
(0, 'joe', '2000-01-01'),
(0, 'mark', '2000-01-12'),
(0, 'adam', '2000-01-21');

create table lastname_history(userid int, name string, timestamp date);
insert into lastname_history values 
(0, 'brown', '2000-01-03'),
(0, 'franklin', '2000-01-21'),
(0, 'hampton', '2000-01-27');
```

Say I've got the above, distinct log tables for first name changes and last name changes. I want a SQL statement to produce the audit log of full names, accounting for simultaneous changes (on `2000-01-21` above both first and last name were changed simultaneously, so that should only be one record).

So for the above I'd want a SELECT statement that produces

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| timestamp  | first | last     |
+------------+-------+----------+
| 2000-01-01 | joe   | NULL     |
| 2000-01-03 | joe   | brown    |
| 2000-01-12 | mark  | brown    |
| 2000-01-21 | adam  | franklin |
| 2000-01-27 | adam  | hampton  |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

Is such a SELECT even possible in SQL? I don't even know what this kind of JOIN would be called.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL and Snowflake.

Comment: A full outer join gets part of the way there but MySQL doesn't have those https://dbfiddle.uk/tfsMNdt2 - and then from that `LAST_VALUE ...` with ignore nulls could copy the last not null value down but MySQL doesn't support "ignore nulls" either! There may well be ways of emulating those though

Comment: I think snowflake is the most likely place I'd be doing queries like this anyway, and your query works there and it appears they support `LAST_VALUE`, which I'm now trying to understand. MySQL would be more just for testing stuff locally, but far less necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Snowflake available to validate on but I believe something like the following should do what you need

```
SELECT COALESCE(lnh.timestamp, fnh.timestamp) AS timestamp,
       COALESCE(lnh.userid, fnh.userid)       AS userid,
      LAST_VALUE(fnh.name) IGNORE NULLS  OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(lnh.userid, fnh.userid)  ORDER BY COALESCE(lnh.timestamp, fnh.timestamp) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS first,
      LAST_VALUE(lnh.name) IGNORE NULLS  OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(lnh.userid, fnh.userid)  ORDER BY COALESCE(lnh.timestamp, fnh.timestamp) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS last
FROM   lastname_history lnh
       FULL OUTER JOIN firstname_history fnh
                    ON lnh.userid = fnh.userid
                       AND lnh.timestamp = fnh.timestamp
ORDER  BY userid, timestamp
```

A SQL Server demo is https://dbfiddle.uk/VorITM-A

Comment: This worked. In Snowflake it needed additional `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, as in Snowflake it uses the entire dataset by default (which just produced five "adam hampton" records) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value#usage-notes

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can try this stupid way. I admit the performance might be degraded. At least there are no special joins nor window functions. On the other hand, correlated subquery and access to `t` alias from innermost subquery was problem on older Oracle, I hope it is ok here.

```
select timestamp
     , (select name from firstname_history where timestamp = (select max(h.timestamp) from firstname_history h where h.timestamp <= t.timestamp)) as first
     , (select name from lastname_history  where timestamp = (select max(h.timestamp) from  lastname_history h where h.timestamp <= t.timestamp)) as last
from (
  select timestamp from firstname_history
  union
  select timestamp from lastname_history
) t
order by timestamp;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/afDayRVG)